# mysql - please advice with correct regexp syntax

Tags: mysql, regex

I am looking for correct query in mysql  db. Let's consider I have tables:

users:

```
id | user_name | desc
--------------------------
1  | john      | tall
2  | john      | fat
3  | maria     | pretty
```

items:

```
id | item_name | color
--------------------------
1  | trousers  | red
2  | shoes     | blue
3  | shoes     | red
```

My search engine searches database to select result with query:

```
SELECT i.item_name, i.color, u.user_name, u.desc 
FROM users u, items i 
WHERE u.id = i.id 
   AND item_name REGEXP $keywords 
   AND user_name REGEXP $keywords
```

Variable $keywords is like this:

```
$keywords = explode(' ', $_POST['keywords']);
$keywords = implode('|', $keywords);
```

Now when $keywords = 'john trousers' it works all fine - i get user with id = 1. It's ok. But when I set $keywords = 'john' it returns empty string. I know even why - there is no 'john' in item_name so my AND condition returns false. The question is:
What is correct regexp expression to return user = 1 with $keywords = "john trousers" and if $keyword = 'john' get two lines - with id = 1 and id = 2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the comparison, using the column value as the search value (and use `LIKE` instead of `REGEXP`):

```
SELECT i.item_name, i.color, u.user_name, u.desc 
FROM users u, items i 
WHERE u.id = i.id 
AND $keywords like concat('%', item_name, '%')
AND $keywords like concat('%', user_name, '%')
```

Note that although this is a neat approach, it only works when `keywords` contains the *whole* value for the column. To make a more sophisticated comparison, you'd need to play with splitting up the values etc (you would have to do your own investigation)

Comment: Well it's surely interesting way to solve the problem. Unfortunatelly the condition that whole value of column must fit keywords messes up :( +1 for you my friend but still waiting for another, more appropriate solution:(